# Weird chars in char array

Tags: c++, arrays, char

I have following function:

```
char * strAlloc(string str) {
    char * chArr = new char[str.size()];

    for (size_t i = 0; i < str.size(); i++) {
        chArr[i] = str[i];
    }

    return chArr;
}
```

if i do a break after `char * chArr = new char[str.size()];` the debugger says following:

```
chArr   0x00c38cf8 "ÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍýýýý««««««««þîþîþ"
```

and if i do a break after the for iteration i get this:

```
chArr   0x00c38cf8 "***************ýýýý««««««««þîþîþ"
```

so what i'm doing wrong?

edit:

```
size_t const gSize = 15; typedef char * 
TMaze [gSize]; 
Maze[0] = strAlloc ("***************");
```

in type TMaze i need the pointer of the char arrays tried also str.size()+1 , 
same behaviour

edit2:

```
char * strAlloc(string const & str) {
    char * chArr = new char[str.size()+1];

    strcpy(chArr, str.c_str());

    return chArr;
}
```

did it!

Comment: The `new` operator doesn't initialise an array's contents, so it's filled with junk when you check its value. For the other question, see Fred's answer.

Comment: Take `str` by const reference: `const string& str`, this saves one unnecessary copy.

Comment: @ipc I think modern compilers can optimise that.

Comment: @MrLister: it can if you remember the `()` on the end.

Comment: @MrLister: Only if the function is inline or if the compiler has LTO. I would not rely on that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're not null terminating. Why not just use `strcpy(chArr, str.c_str());`?

And you'll need to add one to your allocation, too: `char* chArr = new char[str.size() + 1];`

Comment: And `new char[str.size()+1]`.

Comment: @schreda: I think you missed the point. `strcpy()` will null-terminate the char array, your copy loop will not. Adding one to the allocation won't null-terminate, but it will allow space for the null character. You need to either use `strcpy()` as I showed, or modify your code to add a null terminator.

Comment: @schreda Please put that in the question.